# How to create an immutable map from .map() JS

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

So I have a function like this

```
myNewMap = oldMap.map((check) => {
     if (check.get('_id') === against.get('_id')) return check;
});
```

The only problem is myNewMap is the same size as the oldMap (which makes sense), but is there a way to stop this, or do I need a different approach?

Comment: Have you tried to  `filter` it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `filter`

```
myNewMap = oldMap.filter((check) => {
   return check.get('_id') === against.get('_id');
});
```

Or even shorter:

```
myNewMap = oldMap.filter(check => check.get('_id') === against.get('_id'));
```

This will return a new `Map` with only the values that meet the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

After you map over the array you can do

```
Object.seal( yourMappedArrayObject );
```

That will make that object then immutable.

[Object.seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)

Comment: I don't think that's what he was asking.